# How to add List<String> with the same value at selected position to an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to perform some calculations, add a column, and output all results into one single CSV file.

Currently, I have a `ArrayList<List<String>> sorted`, and it holds multiple `List<String>`s, a sample line of the output looks as follows (which is also ONE `List<String>`):

```
[[024eb46690,1418599836,xx,xx,null, 31.622776601683796, 
024eb46690,1418599970,xx,xx,null, 50.99019513592785, 
024eb46690,1418600005,xx,xx,null, 1000.0, 
024eb46690,1418600025,xx,xx,null, 1000.0, 
024eb46690,1418600026,xx,xx,null, 50.99019513592785,
024eb46690,1418600208,xx,xx,null, 1000.0, 
024eb46690,1418600934,xx,xx,null, 1000.0, 
024eb46690,1418602301,xx,xx,null, 1000.0, 
024eb46690,1418602926,xx,xx,null, 1000.0, 
024eb46690,1418603034,xx,xx,null, 1000.0, 
024eb46690,1418603175,xx,xx,null, 1000.0, 
024eb46690,1418603267,xx,xx,null, 1000.0, 
024eb46690,1418603343,xx,xx,null, 1000.0]]
```

- you can ignore the data from the first `xx` onwards, the data is just censored.

I want to delimit the data using the commas, so the data is in the format such that it is `id`, `time` and so on...

So all the lines of data have a different `id`. What i want is to add each line into an arraylist (each line holds a different `id`, because I want to add a new column at the end of each data before collating everything together and then output into a .csv file. So the output should be, with reference to my sample output,

```
024eb46690,1418603343,xx,xx,null, 1000.0, "new column"
```

the value in the new column would be the result of a calculation that has to be refreshed for every id that's why I want to create a new arraylist for each different id. How can I go about doing this? I have almost nine thousand rows of `List<String>`s.

Also, this is what I got

```
for (List<String> sortedList : sorted) {
    for (String s : sortedList) {
        String delimiter = ",";
        String[] splitString = s.split(delimiter);
        String tempID = splitString[0];
    }
}
```

but because for the part where I am performing a calculation, each ID will need a new arraylist to check for duplicates in the other columns, so my method only can do so for ALL the records. Is there away I can improve on this to get what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> id_list;

for (List<String> sortedList : sorted) {
            for (String s : sortedList) {
                String delimiter = ",";
                String[] splitString = s.split(delimiter);
                String tempID = splitString[0];
                if(!id_list.Contains(tempID))
                {
                  id_list.Add(tempID);// duplicates wont add
                  perform calclulations with unique TempID

                }
            }
           s+=","+newColumn;
        }
```

Comment: I tried, but it only works for the first record with the id, for e.g. i have 2 ids, abc and def, but for String s there will be more than one String that uses abc as id! do you have a workaround for that?